Permission denied when mount persistent volume in kubernetes with etcd
This is my deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f ../docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.24.0 (4a2a0458)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: etcd
  name: etcd
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: etcd
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f ../docker-compose.yml
        kompose.version: 1.24.0 (4a2a0458)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: etcd
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: ALLOW_NONE_AUTHENTICATION
              value: "yes"
            - name: ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS
              value: http://0.0.0.0:2379
            - name: ETCD_ENABLE_V2
              value: "true"
            - name: ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS
              value: http://0.0.0.0:2379
          image: bitnami/etcd:3.5.11
          name: etcd
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2379
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/bitnami/etcd"
              name: task-pv-storage
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:  # Add this section
        - name: task-pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: task-pv-claim
status: {}

This is the reference which I follow: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/
And the config:

However when I run I got error:

How do I fix it? Thank for your attention

Run sudo chmod 777 /bitnami/etcd if you want to change permission to directory or else try exec into pod and run chmod 777 /bitnami/etcd and try again.

As per this note if you are using a production environment you need to use  ReadWriteOncePod access mode.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the file to include the configuration and error in plain text?  If you're running a replicated service that needs storage, should it be a StatefulSet, where each replica gets its own automatically-managed PersistentVolumeClaim?
